# Installed Eclipse, but it won't start

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse Kepler had been running just fine until I messed up some settings and then had to delete the installation directory and re-extract the zip file. I also deleted the workspaces.
But after I had extracted the zip file, the Eclipse just won't start.

I tried extracting to another drive (C:) this time, still won't start.

Also tried the `-clean` option, but to no avail.

What went wrong?

[image]

Comment: Close the process from the task manager. It does that sometimes.

Comment: tried, but couldn't end the process from the task manager. Restarted the PC, still the problem persists

Comment: Might be you need java 7?

Comment: What settings did you messed up? Maybe you need Java 7 x64.

Comment: My guess? Your user ID doesn't have execute permissions for the .exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things I could think of that are trivial, but might solve your problem. Maybe you changed `JAVA_HOME` in Path, or deleted it. Check for Environment Variables for `JAVA_HOME`.

Another thing is that you have Java 6 and you need Java 7. Or in your case, you need Java 7 x64. Maybe you have installed Java 7 x64, but `JAVA_HOME` points to another version of Java. Check for that too.

Ultimate solution is to write in `eclipse.ini` argument for desired virtual machine path, like:

```
-vm
/path/to/desired/java/vm
```

Comment: Thanks, added to the eclipse.ini the path to java and then it gave error code 13 which I managed to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can start eclipse with debug / console flag and see exactly what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Run `eclipsec.exe` this will launch Eclipse with a debug console in the background.